# Javascript fetch from file location

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

inside my js I then have:

```
fetch("sdk-article.html").then(stream => stream.text()).then(text => define(text));
```

However when I attempt this the path that it tries is not the full path of the folder. (which means that i can't find the file)

I have also tried: `fetch("-/sdk-article.html").then(stream => stream.text()).then(text => define(text));`

However without luck.

Is there an easy way to load the file from same folder as the file that is requesting it?

**Update the ./sdk-article method**

This doesn't seem to:

```
fetch("./sdk-article.html").then(stream => stream.text()).then(text => define(text));
```

[image]

Comment: For relative paths use `./sdk-articles.html`

Comment: @Keith the path needs to be relative to the root of the public folder.

Comment: _"it tries is not the full path of the folder"_ but then _"from same folder as the file that is requesting it"_. Why _"full path"_ when they are in the same folder?

Comment: Unfortunately JS has no concept of were it's loaded from, the caller does.  As pointed out in comments you could extract the working dir from traversing the document's loaded script, and then parse the URL, but if you have multiple Scripts you then of course need to find the correct script, you could use id's on the script tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is simply load it from the root as followed:

```
fetch("Components/sdk-article/sdk-article.html")
```

Or relatively 
`./sdk-article.html`
(The dot stands for in the current folder)

Comment: This does work however it seems kinda tedious :) is there a simpler way?

Comment: Use the relative path, which i put in after an update :)

Comment: Yeah that doesnt work :( for some reason it doesn't include the Components folder

Comment: You can check if the javascript executing is in the correct path as followed:
```var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
    src = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
alert(src);```

Comment: You will need another `/` at the start, eg.. `fetch("/Component....`

Comment: Did you possibly set a base url? Maybe you forgot a end slash there.

Comment: You can check in the html source if ```<base href=>```is defined